Question about Three mobile operator cellular network coverage in Oban UK
I have multiple Sim cards, and one of my Ukrainian sim card isn't even registered in roaming, however, it is supposed to be working in roaming.
However, I bought it a long time ago and it is Mini-SIM (2FF or 25mmx15mm).
I cannot cut it and I cannot insert it in new smartphones.
So, I can only insert it into my old Samsung C5212 Black Dual phone.
It was very convenient to me since I was using three different cellular phone operators in Ukraine and the new iPhone 11 Pro Max supported only one sim card, so I kept my old Samsung C5212 Black Dual phone for two other sim cards I have.
Now since I moved to UK this poses problem since this phone only supports 2G and UK only supports 3G+.
So my Ukrainian LifeCell simcard is not even registered in the cellular network for roaming.
I have contacted LifeCell support and they told me that there is one UK operator  H3G UK which supports roaming for LifeCell in UK and I should be able manually select H3G UK network in the list of networks on my phone, however, I don't see it and select it.
Over the internet I have read that this operator has been renamed to Three and due to this map
https://mastdata.com/resources/coverage-map.aspx?mnc=20&gen=4&lat=56.41898640753746&lng=-5.48484387666906&z=15.896666666666599 the Three operator should be available in the list of cellular network operators.
I need to receive SMS in roaming to my LifeCell simcard. How can I figure this out?

I understand that no operator in UK supports 2G, my primary concern was to find a place where I can receive SMS and execute USSD codes... looks like I cannot even connect to any external network for this.

It is also dependant on the Oban network coverage, which the UK network regulator Ofcom shows for the four major networks. They have more information here about networks.

Your device is 2G-only and Three have never had a 2G network, they started with 3G (hence the name).
Your phone just won’t ever see the Three network.
Here are a few options you could explore:

Get a newer phone which supports 4G or 5G (3G is in the process of being decommissioned) and that SIM card format (not sure this is easy). Note that in some cases you may need to change the SIM to access more recent networks anyway.
Get a new SIM for the same line, which you could use in a more recent phone. Don’t know if your operator can ship one to you in the UK. You may need to have someone in Ukraine do that for you.
If your carrier and phone support it, get an e-SIM. I’m not quite sure how activation works, especially abroad, though.
Cut the card to the right format. Not necessarily easy, and there’s the risk you may destroy it, but I’m not sure there’s much use for it anyway otherwise.

I haven’t checked the feasibility of any of those options though.

There are phone 'repair' services/shops which will cut simcards to the right size, I have never used them but I guess they are a better bet than doing it yourself.

I do have a newer phone but it supports only one sim card, and I put my other Ukranian simcard there or UK sim card there, so I can't use it... To get a new SIM card I would have to travel back to Ukraine... To get eSim card, I need access to the network and ability to execute USSD code which is not possible without the network....

@Patlatus their website says you can receive a SIM card by mail, though I don’t know if they would send it abroad. If not, can you have someone forward it for you?

Three, formerly Hutchison 3G in the UK never supported 2G. They were built as a 3G network from the start. So if that is the only UK network your home network has a roaming agreement with then you won't be able to use a 2G only phone.
If you can't or don't want to cut the sim down, and can't get a replacement sim that will fit a modern phone, then it seems your only remaining option is to find a phone that is old enough to use "mini sim", but new enough to support at least 3G.
You can pick old smartphones up for next to nothing. I just searched "HTC wildfire S" (the model of phone I used to use until a few years ago) and found them listed on ebay for less than a tenner. I would not reccomend using such an old phone on the Internet anymore, but if all you want is calls and texts then it's probbably ok.
I'm not sure how many phones there were that supported 4G and still used "mini sim".

yes, I understand that no operator in UK supports 2G, my primary concern was to find a place where I can receive SMS and execute USSD codes... looks like I cannot even connect to any external network for this...

@Patlatus so what about Peter's suggestion to buy a 3G capable phone that also has the sim slot that'll fit your sim card? If you want to use a good new phone, you can buy an old phone next to nothing, use USSD to create an eSIM and then add the eSIM to any eSIM phone that you want.

I think it is kind too complex to buy additional phone just for one-time use of executing USSD code, and it is not really guaranteed that this would even work...
